# How to populate remote JSON values in Select in angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript

**Problem :**
Populating JSON values (which is gathered over the REST api) into Select statement?

**team.component.html**

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select Name" [(ngModel)]="name">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let currentName of nameValuesArray" [value]='currentName.name'>
    {{currentName.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**team.component.ts**

```
export class UpdateTeamRosterComponent implements OnInit {

  nameValuesArray;
  name;

  constructor(private fetchData : FetchdataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnIt called');
    this.nameValuesArray = this.fetchData.getAllEmployeeNames('DCP').subscribe(data=>{
      this.nameValuesArray = JSON.stringify(data);
    });

  }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
  UpdateTeamRosterComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[{"name":"Ajith"},{"name":"Anand"},{"name":"Bharath"}]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
      at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3161)
      at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:18623)
      at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:19884)
      at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:19846)
      at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:20480)
      at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:20440)
      at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UpdateTeamRosterComponent.html:2)
      at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:20432)
      at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19828)
      at callViewAction (core.js:20069)
```

*Data is fetching properly from the server*
*Problem is rendering the data on to select*

Comment: You have assigned the return of `this.fetchDatagetAllEmployeeNames('DCP').subscribe` to the `nameValuesArray` variable (this value is an instance of subscription). Then you have assigned the value of the response also to the same object. Both are different things. You can use *ngFor on the data, not on the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the observable to the field.

```
this.nameValuesArray = this.fetchData.getAllEmployeeNames('DCP');
```

Then use [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in the template:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let currentName of nameValuesArray | async" [value]='currentName.name'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern

Comment: It subscribes to the observable from template. And when the component is destroyed, it automatically unsubscribes.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use JSON.stringify , it will convert your array to string, change it as follows

```
this.nameValuesArray = data;
```